# Получение значение из slider Control

Tags: c++, winapi

Как получить значение  SLIDER CONTROL?

```
case WM_HSCROLL:
        if (hwnd == GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_SLIDER1))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            /*r = SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_SLIDER1, TBM_GETPOS, 0, 0);*/
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Нужно выбросить немного мусора, конкретно странный `MessageBox`.

2) Нужно либо использовать `GetDlgItem` совместно с `SendMessage` (при этом лучше все же не портить `hwnd` - вдруг вам потом понадобится хендл окна), либо использовать только `SendDlgItemMessage` (что эквивалентно вызовам `GetDlgItem` + `SendMessage`).

Например, можно записать так:

```
DWORD sliderPos;
switch (...) {
    . . .
    case WM_HSCROLL:
        sliderPos= SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_SLIDER1, TBM_GETPOS, 0, 0);
        . . .
```